# What is use of cordova.build command

Tags: android, cordova

Recently I made a simple mobile application using `apache cordova` documentation. I am using `cli(command line interface)` not using any `eclipse`.

I did everything,As per documentation. everything working fine. I have a doubt regarding following commands.

what is use of `cordova build android` ?

Is it needed to invoke this command, whenever I modify my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Build is a combination of `cordova prepare [platform]` and `cordova compile [platform]`. It will build your .apk-file and put it in platforms/android/ant-build, but it will not launch the app.

Run `cordova build android --release` when your app is ready to be signed and delivered.

Run `cordova --help` for a list of commands.